# click to scroll block by block using animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
}
li {
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
<button>up</button>
<button>down</button>
```

How can when I click on the down button, it will scroll block by block? I know .animate() but couldn't know the logic to achieve what I want ..

Comment: no body know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

i made small function to do tis without plugins 
using jquery like so :

```
$('ul').animate({scrollTop:scrollValue});
```

find the working fiddel :[**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/7L89u207/7/)

Comment: got bug. if u keep clicking up, and then try to click down, there's no respond.

Comment: No issue in the above written code.. It is not a bug. The default delay with the animate function is set to slow. So once you reach to top it completes the delay and then responds back. Kindly check the below code..

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment written in previous answer please check with below code

```
$('#up').click(function(){
$('ul').animate({ "scrollTop": "-=100"},'fast');
}); 
$('#down').click(function(){
$('ul').animate({ "scrollTop": "+=100"},'fast');
});
```

Other than **fast** you can also write

```
$('ul').animate({ "scrollTop": "+=100"},0);
```

Here 0 represents zero delay.

**If you need to delay then kindly follow this code:**

```
var scroll=0;
$('#up').click(function(){
    if(scroll<=0){
        scroll=0;
    }
    else{
        scroll = scroll - 60;
        $('ul').animate({ "scrollTop": scroll});
    }
}); 
$('#down').click(function(){
   if(scroll>=$(document).height() )
   {
       scroll=$(document).height();
   }
    else{
          scroll = scroll + 60;
          $('ul').animate({ "scrollTop": scroll});
        }
});
```

Comment: I got to this point but what if user click the button and then scroll using their mousewheel?

Comment: I don't understand. If user scrolling with mouse wheel and clicking the button then 100 will gets add or subtract from respective position. It's your wish, you can change the value(100)  as per your requirement.

Comment: try scroll with mousewheel and click to scroll repeatly.