# Click to scroll prevention when reached the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

To reproduce my problem, please click on the `down` button for 4 times, and then click on the `up` button. You will notice you have to click one more times for the up bottom to work. How to detect it reached the bottom and return false?

```js
var scrollValue = 0;
$('#down').click(function(){
      scrollValue = scrollValue + 180;
    $('ul').animate({scrollTop:scrollValue});
});

$('#up').click(function(){
      scrollValue = scrollValue + -180;
    $('ul').animate({scrollTop:scrollValue});
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
}
li {
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
<button id="up">up</button>
<button id="down">down</button>
```

Comment: You keep adding to `scrollValue` even though it's limit should be the container `height`.

Comment: @MinusFour I know but what's the logic to solve it?

Comment: This is becoming a bit silly, you got the code here a few hours ago and haven't given the member a chance to improve : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33145472/3168107. Nor did the answer get accepted. But more so, you've received answers way beyond that simple setup here as well : http://stackoverflow.com/q/33146048/3168107.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, like I stated on my comment. You need the container height (with `scrollHeight`) and if the scroll goes farther it needs to be equal to height. Same thing when it tries to go below 0. It must reset to 0.

```
var scrollValue = 0;
var nHeight = $('ul').height();
var height = $('ul').prop('scrollHeight');
height = height - nHeight;
$('#down').click(function(){
      var nScrollValue = scrollValue + 180;
      if(nScrollValue < height){
         scrollValue = nScrollValue;
      } else {
         scrollValue = height;
      }
      $('ul').animate({scrollTop:scrollValue});
});

$('#up').click(function(){
      var nScrollValue = scrollValue - 180;
      if(nScrollValue > 0){
        scrollValue = nScrollValue;
      } else {
        scrollValue = 0;
      }
      $('ul').animate({scrollTop:scrollValue});
});
```

```js
var scrollValue = 0;
var nHeight = $('ul').height();
var height = $('ul').prop('scrollHeight');
height = height - nHeight;
$('#down').click(function(){
      var nScrollValue = scrollValue + 180;
      if(nScrollValue < height){
         scrollValue = nScrollValue;
      } else {
         scrollValue = height;
      }
      $('ul').animate({scrollTop:scrollValue});
});

$('#up').click(function(){
      var nScrollValue = scrollValue - 180;
      if(nScrollValue > 0){
        scrollValue = nScrollValue;
      } else {
        scrollValue = 0;
      }
      $('ul').animate({scrollTop:scrollValue});
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
}
li {
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
<button id="up">up</button>
<button id="down">down</button>
```

I think you should let the browser do this for you, no need to keep track on `scrollValue`:

```
$('#down').click(function(){
      $('ul').animate({scrollTop: '+=180'});
});

$('#up').click(function(){
      $('ul').animate({scrollTop: '-=180'})
});
```

```js
$('#down').click(function(){
      $('ul').animate({scrollTop: '+=180'});
});

$('#up').click(function(){
      $('ul').animate({scrollTop: '-=180'})
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
}
li {
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
<button id="up">up</button>
<button id="down">down</button>
```

Comment: You second snippet is the best answer so far! I tried code here and there, you solved it with 1 line!

Comment: @P.Frank, yeah I just realized there was a small error on the `down` logic. It tried to scroll out the complete height of the div. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollValue = 0;
    nbCase = ($("li").length/3)-1; // 3 is number of visible row
    $('#down').click(function(){
        if(scrollValue <= (nbCase*180)  ){
            scrollValue = scrollValue + 180;
            console.log(scrollValue)
            $('ul').animate({scrollTop:scrollValue});
        }
    });

    $('#up').click(function(){
        if(scrollValue >= (180)  ){
            scrollValue = scrollValue + -180;
            $('ul').animate({scrollTop:scrollValue});
        }
    });
})
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
}
li {
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
<button id="up">up</button>
<button id="down">down</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get the height of the document before you start animating the page scroll, you can use that to compare against the current scroll position

```
var documentHeight = $(document).height();
```

That would get your the total height of your document. If you're animating this inside a separate element, just change $(document) for whichever element you're after

To check when it's reached the bottom, do something like so

```
if(scrollValue + 180 > documentHeight) {
    // At the bottom
}
```

Comment: why get total height of the document? why not get the total height of the `ul`?

Comment: The height of the `ul` is set to 180px in the CSS, so that would always return as 180. It needs to be the height of whatever the container is

Comment: u try to reuse my code and try `$(document).height()` it just won't work. I tried `scrollValue + 180 >= $('ul').height()`, it worked.

Comment: Ah ok, if that works then go with that! I must have a different use case in my head!

Answer (score 0):

Before adding or substracting 180 to your `scrollValue` variable you must first check if it is already in the edge.

Here is the JS:

```
var scrollValue = 0;
$('#down').click(function(){
      if (scrollValue < $(ul).height() ) {
          scrollValue = scrollValue + 180;
          $('ul').animate({scrollTop:scrollValue});
      }
});

$('#up').click(function(){
      if (scrollValue > 0) {
          scrollValue = scrollValue + -180;
          $('ul').animate({scrollTop:scrollValue});
      }
});
```

I am not 100% sure if the comparisons are correct, maybe you should compare to something different than `$(ul).height()`, but this is the right way to go.

Answer (score -1):

You should verify if scrollValue is greater or equal 0 to work. Look the snippet.

```js
var scrollValue = 0;
$('#down').click(function(){
      if(scrollValue >= 0){
         scrollValue = scrollValue + 180;
      }
    $('ul').animate({scrollTop:scrollValue});
});

$('#up').click(function(){
    scrollValue = scrollValue + -180;
    $('ul').animate({scrollTop:scrollValue});
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
}
li {
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
<button id="up">up</button>
<button id="down">down</button>
```

Comment: is ur snippet or example solve my problem? ur demo is broken.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. If down is clicked when scrolled all the way to the bottom, multiple clicks on the up button are still required before it will scroll up. If up is clicked while scrolled to the top, the down button stops working.